# UTF-8 issues in CodeIgniter when fetching data from mysql using codeigniter active record set

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encoding, utf-8

I have applied all tips/tricks available online to enable my codeigniter and mysql with utf8.

I have database and its tables with collation `"utf8_unicode_ci"`.

In html, I have applied meta tag for utf8 : `<meta charset="utf-8">`

In my codeigniter instance, I have reconfirmed setting in:

```
config.php
`$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8'
```

And in `database.php` file, I have:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8'; 
and 
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

When I am showing records using codeigniter active record, it doesn't show utf8 decoded characters whereas when I am running native php-mysql call in same view file
I can see correct characters displayed there. So this confirms that my database and html meta tag is all ok, I can sense the issue on codeigniter part where it is not calling mysql with utf8.

Does any one know how to fix this ?

Thanks..
Anjum

**UPDATE**: For future reference

The language was Herbew which we wanted to show on page. I changed `database.php` setting to:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_swedish_ci';
```

Comment: fixed :) The language was Herbew which we wanted to show on page - I changed database.php setting to                          $db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_swedish_ci';     And it works :)

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question & mark it as correct so that its easily viewable to other users :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed :) The language was Herbew which we wanted to be shown on page. 
I changed database.php setting to 
`$db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';` 
`$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_swedish_ci';`
And it works :)

Comment: Thats a workaroud rather than a solution. It means the data had been added to the db using a latin1 connection. A more appropriate solution would be to leave everything as utf8 and re-add the data (if necessary exporting with a latin1 connection to reimport with a utf8 connection) correctly.